# OpenVPN client should only communicate to VPN server via tunnel; rest via regular NIC

Tags: linux, openvpn

I find a lot of answers to exclude 1 host from the VPN tunnel, but I would like to achieve the opposite.
My server at home gets an internal IP from the ISP, so I've set up a VPN connection so that I can access it from an OpenVPN server in a datacenter.

By default all the traffic on the client is routed through the VPN tunnel, but that's not what I want. All traffic should go via the normal network card (which is much faster) and only traffic from and to the OpenVPN server should go via the tunnel.

Is there a way to achieve this? (I'm running Debian.)

Comment: Do you control the openvpn server?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/408193/how-can-i-configure-openvpn-server-without-push-default-gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openvpn does not redirect all traffic by default, if it's doing that then someone has configured it to do so.

Typically this is done using the "redirect-gateway" setting in the openvpn configuration. This can be set from either the server or the client.

What i'm not sure is if there is a way to override server-pushed configuration from the client if you control the client but not the server.

Comment: Seems it was this line on the server side which was redirecting all traffic over the VPN tunnel: push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" I can't recall adding this line myself, so I assume this is done by default.

Comment: I would guess you copied an example from somewhere without fully understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a few routes in route table. If the destination matches the subnet of data center, then go to tunnel IP address. Others still go to network card.